# In node.js how to request or access specific worker in cluster (with either process ID or worker number)?

Tags: node.js, express

My requirement:
Suppose if there are 4 cores with PIDs (process IDs) 0000,1111,2222,3333. Is there any way to set certain request always handled by particular core.

Is there any way to set ID for specific core and can access that ID in requests?

Example: all requests to 'localhost:8000/info' should always handled by 0000 or any of the above that we can set. If there is a way, how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Step one: stop using cluster
Step two: fire up four node processes on four ports
Step three: put a reverse proxy on port 8000 with rules to distribute to the four node processes

For step three you can use node, nginx, haproxy etc . . .

Comment: I am already using that setup. Inside that particular port there are 4 cores and if nginx redirect to any of the port, we are not sure which core(worker) will take care of it. I want to control that.