# How to send a http request to specified worker in nodejs cluster and do something?

Tags: node.js, markerclusterer

I created a app as follows.

```
if(cluster.isMaster){
   var cpuCount = require('os').cpus().length;
   for (var i = 0; i < cpuCount; i += 1) {
        cluster.fork();
   }
 }else{
  var app = express();
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.send('Hello World!' + + cluster.worker.id);
});
```

I want to check whether the workers work well or not by sending a http request to every worker per 1 sec. When We can't get the response, I will kill the worker and start another worker again.

But I don't know hot to do it. anyone knows how to do it? Or other ways to do it.

Comment: Have each worker have its own web server listening on a unique port and then you can send a request to each of those unique ports and see if it responds.

Comment: No, All of them shared one port.

Comment: You asked how to separately send a request to each worker.  I explained that if each worker has a special web server (used only for this testing) that is listening on its own unique port, you can then separately test each worker's response.  That's one way to identify and test each worker separately.  Yes, I know all of them share one port for the main web server.  I was suggesting a separate server for each that would be used for the testing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In node.js how to request or access specific worker in cluster (with either process ID or worker number)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27571382/in-node-js-how-to-request-or-access-specific-worker-in-cluster-with-either-proc)